# How do you match an array and string together and output the number of matches?

Tags: java, arrays

For example,

I have an array with words: [apple, applet, argyle, addle, car]

I also have an incomplete String: "a _ _ l e"

How would I be able to output the number of possible matches?

For example, "apple" and "applet" can fit in "a _ _ l e" because the letters match and fit in the blank spaces, so it will output 2.

Car obviously cannot fit because it does the first letter of the incomplete word does not start with an a.

Argyle cannot fit either because the fourth letter of the incomplete word is not y.

Same thing for addle with the fifth letter.

EDIT: This is what I have for my code thus far: http://pastebin.com/FasLQ6Tr

EDIT: Thanks Everyone! I was able to get it with everyone's help!

Comment: Have you even begun to think about the problem, or do you just expect SO to do your homework for you?

Comment: There's a powerful (and sometimes confusing :) ) capability called Regex. Have a google at it. there are several sites out there that you can use to practice as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
public boolean equalsGuess(String maskedWord, String word){
 // compare length, take decision
 // convert to char array, iterate through it, ignore comparison for marked char
}
```

Comment: At first I thought this approach makes sense, but in the question it says that _both_ "apple" and "applet" should match against "a__le", which seems to indicate that the pattern doesn't have to begin and end at the beginning and end of the string, but just occur within the string somewhere.

Comment: But then again, "Car obviously cannot fit because it does the first letter of the incomplete word does not start with an a." which suggests that the first letter (and last) letter of the pattern _are_ supposed to match the first (and last) letter of the string.

Answer (score 0):

These types of 'patterns' are what regular expressions were designed for.
You could represent each of your incomplete words as a regular expression, using the wildcard `.` to represent a blank. So, your example would become `{"a..le", ".d."}`.

Then, counting the number of possible matches would be a matter of iterating over all the words for each pattern and incrementing the count if the pattern matches that word:

```
    String[] words = {"apple", "applet", "argyle", "addle", "car"};
    String[] patterns = {"a..le", ".d."};

    int count = 0;
    for (String pattern : patterns) {
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        for (String word : words) {
            if (regex.matcher(word).matches()) count++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(count); // prints 2
```

However, if your data set is huge, regular expressions might be too slow.
In this case, I would suggest implementing a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) to represent each pattern.

Comment: If "apple" and "applet" should both match against "a__le", then it seems like ".d." should match against "addle" at least once, so `count` should be at least `3`, and possibly `4` if we'll count multiple ways of matching.

Comment: But then again, "Car obviously cannot fit because it does the first letter of the incomplete word does not start with an a." which suggests that the first letter (and last) letter of the pattern _are_ supposed to match the first (and last) letter of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 solution:

```
Arrays.asList(array).stream()

    .filter(x -> x.matches("a..le.*"))

    .collect(Collectors.toList()).size()
```